# Error in parsing mibs using build-pysnmp-mibs and loading mibs using pysnmp

Tags: snmp, mib, pysnmp

I am trying to load some custom mibs using mibBuilder.

Initially, as per the pysnmp documentation, I used the build-pysnmp-mib utility for converting the mibs to pysnmp mib format. But I get the following error:

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder

Empty input
smidump -f python hpicfvg.mib | libsmi2pysnmp fails
```

Also, while using the `-k` option, smidump generates a file but the mibBuilder is not able to load the generated file.

I read somewhere that there are bugs in the implementation but I can't find enough documentation or examples on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to compile ICF-VG-RPTR MIB (this is what the hpicfvg.mib file seems to contain) provided you also have the HP-ICF-OID MIB in the smidump search path.